# How to compare versions of treatments

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

I want to compare three different treatments, in my case lamps.
Every lamp has a clear and a matte version, so there is a total of six.

I have deployed them for a number of nights and attracted counts of insects. Friedmans test suggests there are significant differences.

Before comparing the three lamp types I would like to clarify if clear/matte has an effect.

I plan to use Wilcoxon signed rank test to compare all clear/matte pairs.

Or do I have to make three comparisons, one for each lamp type?

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, there are indeed significant differences between treatments, merging your data is not advised as you know that the iid assumption can't be respected.

Another approach would have been to do a two-way Anova or a regression model with the lamp type and the treatment as two factors. But I guess, as you picked the Friedman test, your datas do not meet assumptions required for parametric test and (as I know) there is no straightforward non-parametric alternative to the two-way Anova.

To get back to your question, maybe three wilcoxon test is the way to go, eventually with a correction for multiple comparison to control for type I errors. If it brings significant results, I would advise to run two Friedman test by separating your mate and clear lamps in order to check if it brings the same results.

Disclaimer : I am not a professional, I wait for peer-review to  correct my answer, so don't take my word on your question for the moment.